# SSH without password nor keys

Tags: ssh, authentication

Is there a way to automatize SSH connection (so the script could connect without prompting for password) if the server does not allow using keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if keys are  not allowed on the server (which is .. strange) then you want the ssh-client to read the password from stdin .. which brings us to

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340366/how-to-make-ssh-receive-the-password-from-stdin

Comment: I use personally use "expect", which is the unaccepted answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with putty:

For unix, create a file, paste the below command in, chmod 755

```
putty -ssh ServerNameOrIP -l UserName -pw Password
```

for windows, you can use vbscript like so:

```
Dim ShellRun
Set ShellRun = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ShellRun.Run """C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"" -ssh ServerNameOrIP -l UserName -pw Password", 1
```